# Any English translation for the Atharva Veda Sukta 20.136?

Tags: vedas, translation-request, atharva-veda

I was reading the Griffith translation for the Atharva Veda and came across **[Book 20 Verse 136](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/av/av20136.htm)** which is translated not in English but Latin. **Does anyone have a link to an English translation for the same or can someone share a snapshot if its in a book?**

Comment: Atharva Veda has Kanda-Sukta-Mantra. So, what is the location of the Mantra in this format? It should be something like AV20.136.X.. I think u have missed the X part.

Comment: The Sukta AV 20.136 has 16 Mantras in all. So are u asking for the meanings of all the 16 Mantras or only one among those? It seems u are asking for all the 16? If not then specify the X part so that we can know which particular Mantra u want to know the meaning of.

Comment: the translation I have only goes through the 19th chapter......

Comment: @Rickross yes for the entire lot since the translation I am reading has the entire thing in Latin

Comment: well u can get what u are looking for from [here](http://www.onlineved.com/atharva-ved/?mantra=1&language=1&kand=20&sukt=136). But I'm not being able to copy and paste from that site. So unable to write an answer. @Dr.VineetAggarwal

Comment: @Rickross this seems to be a completely different text compared to the link I shared. Don't know which one is correct.

Comment: @Dr.VineetAggarwal yes the link u have shared seems to be about erotic content.. :O

Comment: Easy lol, go to an online Latin translator and paste the verses one by one, until you have a full compilation.

Comment: Errr a translation of a translation that too using a software is definitely not the same thing as a direct translation done by a scholar.